# Making a confirm box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make my own dialog box. I want to use jquery for this. For some buttons on my site I need a confirmation dialog (like "Are you sure you want to delete" yes/no). When the dialog is active, the rest of the site should not be clickable.

So, I made this:

```
<div class="overlay" id="overlay" style="display:none;">
  <div class="overlaycontent" id="overlaycontent">
    <div id="overlaytext" class="overlaytext ">
      <span id="overlaymessage" class="mediumtext bold">Deze klant verwijderen?</span>
      <br><br>
      <button id="nobutton" class="button1 highbutton hand" onclick="confirmno()">Nee</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <button id="yesbutton" class="button2 highbutton hand" onclick="confirmyes()">Ja</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

ID overlay is over the whole page.
ID overlaycontent creates a white box on top of it.
ID overlaytext centers the message
ID overlaymessage contains the question/message.
ID nobutton is the button to say no :)
ID yesbutton is.. guess what :)

Now, the javascript to display a message:

```
function confirm(message,nobutton,yesbutton){
$('#overlaymessage').html(message);
$('#nobutton').html(nobutton);
$('#yesbutton').html(yesbutton);
$('#overlay').show();
}
function confirmno(){
$('#overlay').hide();
}
function confirmyes(){
????
}
```

So far, it works fine (except the yes button of course, please read further on), but for the next step I lack the knowledge. Say that I have a button somewhere to delete a user on my website.

```
<button class="redbutton" onclick="deleteuser(22)">
```

The button needs javascript like:

```
<script language="javascript">
function deleteuser(userid){
  confirm('Delete user?','No','Yes');
  ??????  
}
</script>
```

Now where the question marks are, I want the function to do something based on the fact the user clicked yes or no. How to catch this? I don't have any idea. Please help me out. I don't want to use Jquireui.dialog.

Comment: You need the confirm function to accept callbacks that get called when each button is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble here is that you can't pause execution in javascript, so you'll need to adjust your confirm function (which you should probably rename, by the way, since JS has a native confirm function).  Get rid of the onclick of your yes button, and adjust your confirm function like so:

```
function confirm(message,nobutton,yesbutton,yesfunction){
  $('#overlaymessage').html(message);
  $('#nobutton').html(nobutton);
  $('#yesbutton').html(yesbutton);
  $('#overlay').show();
  $('#yesbutton').off("click").click(yesfunction);
}
```

Then, pass a function into your confirm call:

```
function deleteuser(userid){
  function deleteConfirmed() {
    // delete code here
  }
  confirm('Delete user?','No','Yes',deleteConfirmed);
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that addresses the fact that jQuery won't stop the execution of the code after calling the OP's `confirm()` function.

Comment: Thanks for this, it works like a charm! One last question. After the yes button is clicked, I want the overlay div to disppear, I tried "$('#yesbutton').off("click").click(yesfunction).$('#overlay').hide()" but that does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to capture the result from your confirm dialogue box e.g.

```
var x = confirm("Are you sure you are ok?");
if (x) {
    alert("Good!");
} else {
    alert("Too bad");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this.

```
<script language="javascript">
function deleteuser(userid){
  if(confirm('Delete user?')) {
     //'Ok' is clicked
  }
  else {
     //'Cancel' is clicked
  }
}
</script>
```